# MS Excel 2010 - Multiple PivotTables using the same filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I have the need to place multiple PivotTables on the same sheet in Excel that all come from the same dataset.  I would like all of the Pivot Tables on the sheet to use the same "Page Filter".  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Slicers are the way to go

Click on the pivot table... click insert -> slicer

to connect to an additional pivot table, right click on the slicer... go to pivot table connections and ticky the other pivot table.

Now when you click the slicer it will filter both pivot tables.